# forwardRef : No me muestra el ícono de "Editar" en material-react-table

Tags: reactjs, table, icons, material

Estoy tratando de implementar en un proyecto "material-react-table" pero al momento de querer mostrar el ícono en el renglón de la tabla, no lo muestra y tampoco me marca error. Entonces, estoy confundido. Es obvio, que algo estoy haciendo mal.

Instale:
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
npm install material-table @material-ui/core --save
npm install @material-ui/icons --save

A continuación mi código del formulario:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';  
import Api from "../../servicios/api";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import  {Button, Container, Modal, ModalBody, ModalHeader, FormGroup, ModalFooter}  from 'reactstrap';
import { forwardRef } from 'react';  
import { MaterialReactTable, useMaterialReactTable } from 'material-react-table'; 
import Edit from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';


const Enfermedades = () => {   
    
     
        
    
     
                //--Estructura de la tabla
                const columnas =[  
                    { 
                        accessorKey:'Id_enfermedad', //campo de la tabla
                        header:'ID' 
                    },
                    { 
                        accessorKey:'Nombre_enf', //campo de la tabla
                        header:'Enfermedad' 
                    },
                    {
                        accessorKey:'Descrip', //campo de la tabla
                        header:'Descripción' 
                    } 
            ]

            const tableIcons = {
                
                Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />)
               
              };
              
              const tableRef = React.createRef();


        return ( 
            
  <Container>
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-header">  
                                <br></br>
                                <Button color='success' onClick={()=>abrirCerrarmostrarmodalInsertarEnfermedades()}>Agregar Nueva Enfermedad</Button>
                                <br></br>
                                <h4>Lista de Enfermedades</h4>
                            <div className="card-body">
                                     
                                         <MaterialReactTable 
                                                                   columns={columnas}
                                                                   tableRef={tableRef}
                                                                   icons={tableIcons}
                                                                   data={enfermedades}
                                                                   title="Lista de Enfermedades" 
                                                                   actions={[
                                                                          {
                                                                            icon: Edit,
                                                                            tooltip:"Modificar Información de la Enfermedad",
                                                                            onClick:(event, rowData)=>abrirCerrarmostrarmodalModificarEnfermedades(rowData.Id_enfermedad)
                                                                          }
                                                                   ]}
                                                                               
                                        />
                                     
                           
</Container>   
         );
    }
 
export default Enfermedades;
```

Cabe aclarar que si muestra la información de mi API y además, muestra los íconos predeterminados que tiene la tabla (buscar filtrar... etc), pero, como lo dije antes algo estoy haciendo mal / algo me falta para mostrar dicho ícono. ¿Alguna solución?.

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score -1):

El Hook `forwardRef` no se recomienda, ya no es parte de la documentación actual de `react`.

No se puede pasar `ref` como `props` en `functional components`, es una palabra reservada, debes crear tu nombre de `prop`:

```
//esto es invalido
<Edit {...props} ref={ref} />
```

---

```
//Esto puede funcionar
<Edit {...props} myRef={myRefHookName} />
```

---

Intenta algo así:

```
const tableIcons = {
                
                Edit: <Edit {...props} myRef={myRefHookName} />
               
              };
```

Comment: Un voto negativo solo porque "sientes", vaya pendejo haciendo mal uso de la plataforma, ahora justifica porque, ya que lo que se esta compartiendo en esta respuesta es cierto.